# How to Calculate a Letter Grade Without if/else Statements C++

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement

In the program I am supposed to assign a letter grade based on the user's total points.  I know how to do this using if/else statements i.e.:

```
if (score <= 100 && score > 93)
   cout << "You have received an A";
else if (score <= 93 && score > 89)
   cout << "You have received an A-";
else if etc.etc.etc.
```

I'm wondering how to calculate the letter grade without the string of if/else statements.  These are the instructions:

> Store all of the possible letter grades in a constant array of strings, and then come up with an algorithm that uses the total point count to compute an index into the array to return the letter grade. This avoids the use of a long string of if/else statements.

Here is what I have so far (without all the bells and whistles of the entire program):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int userInput;

    string gradeData[] { "A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-", "C+", "C", "C-", "D+", "D", "D-", "F" };

    cout << "What are your total number of points?: ";
    cin >> userInput;

    cout << "\nYour final grade is " << **INSERT CALL TO GRADE CALCULATION FUNCTION HERE** << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

My plan is to write a function that does this and returns the letter grade to the user, but I really don't know where to start.  Would it possibly involve using a two dimensional array?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just write a string of if statements. Simpler and more understandable than any other possible (complicated) solution.

Comment: So, given a score of N points, how do you find the relevant letter grade?  There are only 101 values to consider: 0…100; that's not a very big array (but it is a very boring one).

Comment: You're being asked to write an *algorithm* to compute an index into that array. so if the score is 94-100 you would need to come up with 0 (given your string array).

Comment: @Ed Heal I'd much rather do it that way, but we're supposed to avoid a string of logic statements, despite it being simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to do it.. You must first scale/normalize your grade value within a specific range. That range is from: `1 --> grades.length`. Where `grades.length` is your string array.

Now since the string array is from `A --> F` instead of `F --> A`, you must reverse/flip the grade by doing `grades.length - scaled_grade`.

For example, if grade was  100 and we scaled it down between 1 and 12. We'd get 11. `Grades[11]` is F.  `Grades[Grades.length - 11]` is A.

The following code will demonstrate my above explanation.. I cannot explain things very well..

```
#include <iostream>

int scale(int minimum, int maximum, int value, int maxrange = 1, int minrange = 0)
{
    return ((maxrange - minrange) * (value - minimum))/(maximum - minimum) + minrange;
}

int main()
{
    const std::string grades[] = {"A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-", "C+", "C", "C-", "D+", "D", "D-", "F"};

    int size = sizeof(grades) / sizeof(grades[0]);
    int grade = 0;

    std::cout<<"Enter your grade: ";
    std::cin>>grade;
    std::cin.ignore();

    int g = size - scale(0, 100, grade, size, 1);
    std::cout<<"Your grade is: "<<grades[g];
}
```

Live test case: http://ideone.com/2qVRQS

*

```
stdin is set to 50, it will print C.
stdin is set to 100, it prints A.
stdin is set to 0, it prints F.
```

*

and so on..

Comment: This makes the assumption that the range of marks are the same for each grade.

Comment: Yes it does but imo, it is better than filling in an array of 100 grades. Without such an assumption, you'd need branching/if-statements/switch-cases, etc..

Answer (score 3):

Try this ...

```
string gradeData[100] = {
   "F", // For person not turning up and scoring nothing
   "F", // For the person turning up and managing to sit down
   "F", // For the person turning up and managing to face the right direction
   "F", // For the person turning up and managing to write something in the name box
   "F", // For the person turning up and managing to spell their name right
   "E", // For the person able to open the question paper

   ....

   "C", // For the person getting 50% of the questions nearly right

   ...

   "A+" // For the swot at the front

 };

 cout << "Your grade is " << gradeData[score] << endl;
```

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: In Japan we actually have `E` as a letter grade, it is the equivalent of `F` in the U.S. I think countries do not use ***both*** E and F because of how easy it would be to change an F to an E ;)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman - If you got an E/F would you even both to tell your employer?